# Is it possible to reject publish if SNAPSHOT dependencies are used in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, publishing, snapshot, sbt-plugin

I keep accidentally publishing my internal project still referencing internal SNAPSHOTs, but it would be very helpful if there was an SBT plugin that would fail to publish if you are relying on any SNAPSHOT dependencies.  Is anyone aware of such a plugin or feature in SBT?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how you can write such plugin.

#### output

```
> publish
[info] :: delivering :: com.example#b_2.10;0.1.0 :: 0.1.0 :: release :: Fri Jan 13 15:50:53 EST 2017
[info]  delivering ivy file to /xxx/b/target/scala-2.10/ivy-0.1.0.xml
[info] Wrote /xxx/b/target/scala-2.10/b_2.10-0.1.0.pom
[info] Wrote /xxx/a/target/scala-2.10/a_2.10-0.1.0.pom
[info] :: delivering :: com.example#a_2.10;0.1.0 :: 0.1.0 :: release :: Fri Jan 13 15:50:53 EST 2017
[info]  delivering ivy file to /xxx/a/target/scala-2.10/ivy-0.1.0.xml
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last b/*:publishConfiguration for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last a/*:publishConfiguration for the full output.
[error] (b/*:publishConfiguration) SNAPSHOT found in classpath:
[error] com.eed3si9n:treehugger_2.10:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT:compile->default;compile->compile;compile->runtime;compile->default(compile);compile->master
[error] (a/*:publishConfiguration) SNAPSHOT found in classpath:
[error] com.eed3si9n:treehugger_2.10:0.2.4-SNAPSHOT:compile->default;compile->compile;compile->runtime;compile->default(compile);compile->master
[error] com.example:c_2.10:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile->compile;compile->default(compile)
[error] io.netty:netty-all:4.1.8.Final-SNAPSHOT:compile->default;compile->compile;compile->runtime;compile->default(compile);compile->master
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 13, 2017 3:50:53 PM
```

#### project/build.properties

```
sbt.version = 0.13.13
```

#### project/DepsVerifyPlugin.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object DepsVerifyPlugin extends sbt.AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = plugins.JvmPlugin
  override def trigger = allRequirements
  override def projectSettings = Seq(
    publishConfiguration := {
      val old = publishConfiguration.value
      val ur = update.value
      ur.configuration("compile") foreach { compileReport =>
        val allModules = compileReport.allModules
        val snapshotDeps = allModules filter { _.revision contains "SNAPSHOT" }
        if (snapshotDeps.nonEmpty) {
          sys.error(
            "SNAPSHOT found in classpath:\n" +
            snapshotDeps.mkString("\n")
          )
        }
      }
      old
    }
    )
}
```

#### build.sbt

```
val commonSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] = Seq(
    organization in ThisBuild := "com.example",
    scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.10.6",
    version      in ThisBuild := "0.1.0",
    resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("public"),
    publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/test-repo")))
  )

val netty = "io.netty" % "netty-all" % "4.1.8.Final-SNAPSHOT"
val treehugger = "com.eed3si9n" %% "treehugger" % "0.2.4-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(a, b, c)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    name := "Hello",
    publish := ()
  )

lazy val a = (project in file("a"))
  .dependsOn(b, c)
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies += netty
  )

lazy val b = (project in file("b"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    libraryDependencies += treehugger
  )

lazy val c = (project in file("c"))
  .settings(
    commonSettings,
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    publish := ()
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider adopting [sbt-release](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-release).

This is a more high-level 'workflow' plugin: 'publish' is used as one of the steps in a release (after 'check that there's no SNAPSHOT dependencies').

It will not prevent you from running 'sbt publish', but when you make a habit of using 'sbt release' instead of 'sbt publish' it accomplishes what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into this further.